# Average number of toss required

Tags: probability, combinatorics

One of my friends ask this question but I could not answer.

A fair coin is tossed till both head and tell appear repeatedly at once. Find the average number of toss required.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what "both head and tail appear repeatedly at once" means in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: $3$ tosses.

Working:

Let random variable $X$ be the number of tosses needed to achieve consecutive tosses being the same.

Define the event $A_n =$ "consecutive H or consecutive T occurred for the first time after $n$ tosses" for $n=2,3,\ldots$.

For $A_n$ to occur, the first toss can be either $H$ or $T$, but whichever it is that determines exactly what the next $n-1$ tosses must be.

For example, if $n=5$, then if the first toss is H, we need HTHTT. If the first toss is T then we need THTHH.

Each toss is independent and for each toss $P\left(H\right) = P\left(T\right) = \frac{1}{2}$.

So $P(A_n) = \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}$.

The average number of tosses required is then:

\begin{eqnarray*}
E\left[X\right] &=& \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{nP\left(A_n\right)} \\
&=& \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{n\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}} \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2} - 1 \qquad\left(\mbox{see below *}\right) \\
&=& 3
\end{eqnarray*}

$*$ To evaluate the sum $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{n\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}}$ we can apply a little calculus to the well known sum $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^n} = \dfrac{1}{1-n} - 1 - \frac{1}{2}$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mbox{Let}\qquad f\left(x\right) &=& \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{nx^{n-1}},\qquad 0\lt x\lt 1. \\
\mbox{Then integrating,}\qquad F\left(x\right) &=& \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{x^n} \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{1-x} - 1 - x \\
\mbox{Then differentiating,}\qquad f\left(x\right) &=& \dfrac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^2} - 1 \\
\mbox{Thus,} \qquad \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{n\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}} &=& f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
&=& \dfrac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2} - 1 \\
&=& 3.
\end{eqnarray*}